# 'it + be + noun phrase + relative clause' : Is this pattern always a restrictive clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

1. John **,** who was injured **,** left the field.
2. **It** was John who was injured , not Brown (This is a restrictive clause, because there is no comma after John)

Question 1: In the second sentence: Can we use a comma after John, as non-restrictive relative clause? 
Question 2. Or when a relative clause is used with '*It*' to emphasize the noun (*John*), is the relative clause considered as a **restrictive** relative clause?

More examples: 3 .It was England which Brown lives in.
4. It was in 1993 that it happened.

Answer (score 2):

> a. It was John who was injured, not Brown.
>
> b. It was England which Brown lives in.
>
> c. It was in 1993 that it happened.

All three examples involve *it*-cleft constructions. The usual punctuation convention is to ***not*** insert a comma between the matrix clause and its relative clause. For example:

- It was John [*who was injured*].

In the above example, the matrix clause is "It was John", and its relative clause is what is in italics *"who was injured"*. Some grammar books will refer to that relative clause as an ***integrated relative clause***.

(ASIDE: Instead of the term *integrated relative clause*, some of the older grammars use the older term ***restrictive relative clause***. The use of the term *restrictive relative clause* can often be misleading, for that kind of relative clause does not always have a restrictive kind of functionality.)

In an *it*-cleft, the relative clause does not have a restrictive kind of functionality.

In general, the *it*-cleft's relative clause is used to hold the background info, while the matrix clause is used to foreground the important info. For example:

- b. It was **England** *which Brown lives in.*

The important info is "England", and it is foregrounded via the matrix clause. The less important info is backgrounded via the relative clause (since we can usually assume that Brown does live somewhere, and so, that info can be backgrounded, that he lives somewhere). A corresponding canonical type of clause could be *"Brown lives in England"*.

Comment: When we say " _It was John who was injured_" (without comma) ,Doesn't it mean there might be other persons named John ?

Comment: @Dinusha No, what it means is *"John was injured."* -- We would use your example (the it-cleft) when we already know that someone was injured but we don't know who that person was, and so the speaker wants to emphasis to us that the unknown person was John.

Comment: It was England which Brown lives in? *which* or *where*?

Comment: @Maulik V I think 'It was England which Brown lives in' is equal to 'It was England where Brown lives'

Comment: @Dinusha I don't think so. *Which* selects from more than one England it seems! :) But that could be just me! :P

Comment: In *It was dangerous what she did*, is *what she did* an integrated clause? If so does that mean *dangerous what she did* is a constituent?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were making out that that kind of relative clause would be termed a restrictive clause by those who don't believe in non-integrated relative clauses. I don't think it would. H&P, as I get their take on it - without checking - would not regard *John who was injured* as a constituent. It's more that the relative clause isn't supplementary, so it's can't be described as not integrated into the grammatical structure of the sentence. But that relative clause is not grammatically adjoined to its antecedent. It's a different animal from a normal 'integrated' relative clause ...

Comment: OK, only just understood your comment. How about, "It was *dangerous* what Mary did, not wreckless". (I think that would be regarded as a relative clause?)

Comment: Oh, and nice post +1 :) The back-grounding's really important and is heavily reflected in the intonation too. Useful to put in there ...

Comment: Yes, so it's integration there's in contrast with not being supplementary, as opposed to integrating with a noun, for example, to become a constituent? (I'm one comment behind you, I think!)

Comment: So, one last question - if that's ok - the antecedent for *who*, for example, in your *John* sentence is *John*; even though the RC isn't headed by John?

Comment: I think I understood what you meant anyhow. Thing is, when these have a wh- word, they seem more like free relatives to me, just in a how they feel kind of way ...

Comment: Hey, please don't delete them yet!:) I need some time to reflect and, erm, retract my *free relative* (yes, yes, yes, I know, I know) and explicate my *fused relative* confusion ...

Answer (score -1):

> John, who was injured, left the field.

The comma after *'John'* plays a crucial role in *introducing* John. Who John? The one who was injured. So, here, the comma makes the sense.

> It was John who was injured, not Brown

The comma after *'injured'* is merely *separating* John from Brown. It does not introduce John the way the first sentence does. You can't use comma after John. *It was...* already introduces him!

There's a clear difference between restrictive/non-restrictive. Non-restrictive clauses would generally have two commas.

[Very good read is here.](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/)

Comment: Here's an example of a non restrictive relative clause in a cleft sentence: "It was John, who was injured, who left the field".

Comment: @tunny What is the difference between cleft sentence "_It was John, who was injured._" (non-restrictive) and "_It was John who was injured._" (restrictive)?

Comment: In "It was John, who was injured, who left the field",  the information that John was injured is extra information, not essential to the main clause "It was John who left the field. The commas round the non-restrictive clause act in a similar way to brackets. In "It was John who was injured, the "who was injured" is essential to the meaning of the whole sentence.

Comment: @tunny did I say something different in my answer than your last comment? :)

Comment: No. I was merely responding to a question from Dinusha, who seemed unclear about the non-restrictive clause I had used in a cleft sentence.